# How can I write this canvas painting loop with a JS iterator?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, iterator, generator

I'm reading through an article about continuously drawing frames of an HTML5 video player on canvas. I heard about JS iterators a while back and I think there's supposedly a performance advantage, so I'd like to know how to write this set of canvas painting functions into an Iterator:

```
function canvasVideo(){
    //DECLARE VARIABLES

    var $videoPlayer = $('#Video-Player');
    var $canvasPlayer = $('#Canvas-Player');
    var videoPlayer = $videoPlayer[0];
    var canvasPlayer = $canvasPlayer[0];
    var context = canvasPlayer.getContext("2d");

    //DEFINE FUNCTIONS

    //draw the video
    function  draw() {

      //Background
      context.fillStyle = '#ffffaa';
      context.fillRect(0, 0, canvasPlayer.width, canvasPlayer.height);

      //video
      context.drawImage(videoPlayer , 0, 0);

   }

   //update canvas at set interval with video frames
    function canvasRun(int){

        //set timer with interval
        var canvasTimer = setTimeout(canvasRun, int);

        //draw the video frame
        draw();
    }
    function videoLoaded(event){
        canvasRun(20);
    }

    //HANDLE EVENTS

    $videoPlayer.on("canplaythrough", function (){
        videoLoaded();
    });
}
```

How can this be done with JS Iterators?

I've tried using tutorials to learn iterators, but the generic examples have confused me, and think seeing it done with an example like this would help me learn.

Comment: "*I heard about JS iterators a while back and I think there's supposedly a performance advantage*" - no. Where did you hear this? Also, I don't see how they would be applied here.

Comment: Why do you need so strange thing? I stronly recommend you to read about [requestAnimationFrame](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window/requestAnimationFrame) instead

Comment: @Bergi I thought they could be used to do recursive functions more efficiently. ill go back and read more then

Comment: @JonathanTodd: Well, they can be used as a different *notation* for tail-recursive (and even pseudo-recursive, i.e. asynchronous) functions, but they don't necessarily make them more efficient. Given that generators are a relatively new feature, they're not as optimised as well.